# How to debug slow login

Tags: login, debugging

NOTE: *Login*, not boot.

On Ubuntu 20.04.

After entering my password, my wallpaper appears, and some version of the bars (when using Gnome). Everything is frozen for a minute before waking up.

Same thing when I login with another WM. Even the mouse freezes.

There is no `~/.Xerrors`.

Other users on that machine don't have that problem.

I would like to know where to look?

---

Thanks @waltinator for the hint, here is an interesting part of `journalctl`:

```
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2437]: Starting Dropbox...Dropbox isn't running!
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2437]: Done!
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: emacs is /usr/bin/emacs
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: gnome-terminal is /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: .xmonad/xmonad-session-rc: line 81: type: gnome-power-manager: not found
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: .xmonad/xmonad-session-rc: line 84: type: xfce4-power-manager: not found
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: unclutter is /usr/bin/unclutter
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2665]: 2664
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: nm-applet is /usr/bin/nm-applet
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.se>
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian systemd[2180]: Created slice apps.slice.
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian systemd[2180]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Nov 09 08:13:57 ionian systemd[2180]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 09 08:13:58 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Nov 09 08:13:58 ionian systemd[2180]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Nov 09 08:13:58 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2480]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-109.4.517/PyQt5.QtNetwor>
Nov 09 08:13:58 ionian NetworkManager[957]: <info>  [1604906038.9643] agent-manager: agent[aa291371d84b936a,:1.86/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent regis>
Nov 09 08:13:58 ionian systemd[2180]: Started VTE child process 2695 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2672.
Nov 09 08:13:59 ionian nm-applet[2666]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Nov 09 08:14:00 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2480]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-109.4.517/PyQt5.QtDBus.c>
Nov 09 08:14:05 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' unit='dunst.service>
Nov 09 08:14:05 ionian systemd[2180]: Starting Dunst notification daemon...
Nov 09 08:14:05 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Nov 09 08:14:05 ionian systemd[2180]: Started Dunst notification daemon.
Nov 09 08:14:09 ionian tracker-store[2282]: OK
Nov 09 08:14:09 ionian systemd[2180]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Nov 09 08:14:29 ionian systemd[1]: Started Daemon for generating UUIDs.
Nov 09 08:14:35 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2667]: Identity added: /home/gauthier/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/gauthier/.ssh/id_rsa)
Nov 09 08:14:36 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: XMonad is recompiling and replacing itself another XMonad process because the current process is cal>
Nov 09 08:14:36 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/gauthier/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Nov 09 08:14:36 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: XMonad skipping recompile because it is not forced (e.g. via --recompile), and neither xmonad.hs nor>
Nov 09 08:14:43 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.serv>
Nov 09 08:14:43 ionian systemd[2180]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Nov 09 08:14:43 ionian dbus-daemon[2197]: [session uid=1000 pid=2197] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Nov 09 08:14:43 ionian systemd[2180]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Nov 09 08:15:13 ionian tracker-store[2874]: OK
Nov 09 08:15:13 ionian systemd[2180]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Nov 09 08:16:54 ionian anacron[944]: Job `cron.daily' started
Nov 09 08:16:54 ionian anacron[2915]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2020-11-09
Nov 09 08:16:54 ionian cracklib[2951]: no dictionary update necessary.
Nov 09 08:17:01 ionian CRON[2977]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 09 08:17:01 ionian CRON[2980]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 09 08:17:01 ionian CRON[2977]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 09 08:17:58 ionian PackageKit[1957]: daemon quit
Nov 09 08:17:58 ionian systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Nov 09 08:18:27 ionian systemd[2180]: Started VTE child process 3359 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2672.
Nov 09 08:19:35 ionian systemd[2180]: Started VTE child process 3407 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 2672.
Nov 09 08:19:37 ionian systemd[2180]: vte-spawn-6db52a4c-8401-455e-a2c0-9094b0a5ae2e.scope: Succeeded.
Nov 09 08:19:37 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2321]: user error (Error in function getWindowAttributes)
Nov 09 08:20:20 ionian fstrim[960]: /: 61,7 GiB (66186797056 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
Nov 09 08:20:20 ionian systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Nov 09 08:20:20 ionian systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
Nov 09 08:20:20 ionian systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.144s (kernel) + 8min 29.987s (userspace) = 8min 34.132s.
Nov 09 08:20:25 ionian anacron[944]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Nov 09 08:20:25 ionian anacron[944]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Nov 09 08:20:25 ionian systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
```

There is a minute long gap after `pam_unix`, until `PackageKit` daemon quit. I'm not sure why PAM is even doing anything, there is no remote account management. Should I blame PackageKit?

Note that logging out and back in again is fast.

---

New log with suspicious Dropbox:

```
Nov 10 08:15:12 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6403]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1>
Nov 10 08:15:17 ionian systemd[6105]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Nov 10 08:15:23 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6403]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1>
Nov 10 08:15:24 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6403]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1>
Nov 10 08:15:24 ionian xdg-desktop-por[6401]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could >
Nov 10 08:15:27 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6403]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1>
Nov 10 08:15:27 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6403]: dropbox: load fq extension '/home/gauthier/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-1>
Nov 10 08:15:32 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6352]: Starting Dropbox...Dropbox isn't running!
Nov 10 08:15:32 ionian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6352]: Done!
```

I've tried deactivating Dropbox from the "Startup Applications", but the check mark keeps coming back. What could possibly cause that?

I'm trying to remove it from Startup Applications altogether, instead of just unchecking it, maybe that will do it. Could it be so that starting Dropbox that way is a deprecated way?

Comment: Hard to say but startup applications would be a good place to start, perhaps a large program is opening? Also check the home/autostart folder, if it exists. Are any hard drives mounted at log in?

Comment: `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` just after you login might show interesting log messages.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks, I've look into the Startup Applications, and unselected everything. It doesn't help, but I noticed Dropbox keeps selecting itself back. I also sometimes get a warning that Dropbox wants to install its daemon, although it's already running and syncing.

Comment: @waltinator: thanks! I've edited my question to show the result

Comment: @Gauthier Have you tried creating a new account and seeing if that account is equally slow?  At least you would find out whether it's a "problem" with your current account (i.e., existing settings) or your system itself.

Comment: @Ray: "Other users on that machine don't have that problem". It might be because that other user is not sudoer.

Comment: @Gauthier Other users not having the problem is not the same as whether or not it happens when you create a new user.  For example, has this computer been updated from a previous version of Ubuntu?  And if so, is your account "older" than the other users?  If both are "true", then it's possible you have some old configuration files in `~/.config/`, etc. that is causing the login to be slow.  You could remove all of your configuration files, but it would be easier and less destructive if you tried a new user account instead (and give it sudo access).

Comment: @Ray Right. So a new user within the sudo group does not show that slow login. There's something about Startup Applications and Dropbox that seems fishy, edited to add.

Comment: @Gauthier So, I've experience something "similar" to what you're seeing but with older versions of Ubuntu.  I am attached to my personalised settings, but ultimately, it wasn't worth the time to figure out which one was causing me problems.  So, yeah...I just deleted my settings.   And then re-configured the few settings that I do care about (i.e., hotkeys, etc.).  I find the settings directories to be somewhat bloated...I only care about a few but they're all dumped into one directory and it's hard to sort them out.Sorry, didn't mean to whine! :-) Best of luck to you; sorry I can't help more!

Comment: @Gauthier Just a random thought...  I think Dropbox used to be installed separately.  That is, we installed `nautilus-dropbox` and then it separately downloads and installs Dropbox.  Maybe this process didn't work well for you for the Ubuntu upgrade?  Maybe try uninstalling Dropbox and installing it back again?

Comment: @Ray I feel you. I placed the settings I really care about are in a git repository at `~/dotfiles`. I have a script there that sets symlinks into the various places settings may be, when possible. It's a little hassle to setup, but wonderful when installing on a new machine.

Comment: @Gauthier Ah!  Thank you for the insight!  So that's what other more experienced people do?  That is probably what I should try.  I rarely install a new machine but when I do, it is really annoying...  Thank you!